# How to split RAID 1 disk created under Windows Server

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

I got a RAID 1 created under Windows Server 2012, as you can see :

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
[...]Disklabel type: gpt[...]
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2    2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  262178 5860533134 5860270957  2.7T Microsoft LDM data


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
[...]Disklabel type: gpt[...]
Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sdb2    2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3  262178 5860533134 5860270957  2.7T Microsoft LDM data
```

"ldmtool scan" returns the RAID 1 and I got no problem mounting it.

I want to "separate" the disk so I can mount only /dev/sda and extract the files I want. /dev/sdb need to be empty during this time.

Can I just format /dev/sdb then mount /dev/sda with ldmtool or will I loose data ? I think we can just format /dev/sdb as there is a RAID 1 but I prefer to be sure that ldmtool can always mount /dev/sda if /dev/sdb is no longer present.

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : It works well with ldmtool, but I don't know if it will work "all-time", as always make backup and think twice before doing something like that.

In my particular case it appears that it was a RAID0 and not a RAID1 so, in this case, just don't do it (might seems pretty obvious)